# Incorrect SQL Syntax Error Message

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do I fix the following error? I think the issue is with the `INSERT INTO` part of my SQL query.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

### Code:

```
<?php

if  (isset($_POST['submitted'])){
    include('../mysqli_connect.php');


if (isset($_POST['$pn, $pc,$ps,$pd'])); 

        if(!empty($_POST['product_name'])){
        echo'<p> Successful entry.</p>';
        $pn = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, trim($_POST['product_name']));
        $pn=$_POST['product_name'];
        echo "You chose:".$pn."<br>";}
        else{
            echo '<p>You forgot to enter the product name.</p>';}


        if(!empty($_POST['product_category'])){
        echo'<p> Successful entry.</p>';
        $pc = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, trim($_POST['product_category']));
        $pc=$_POST['product_category'];
        echo "You chose:".$pc."<br>";}
        else{
            echo '<p>You forgot to enter the product category.</p>';}


        if(!empty($_POST['product_supplier'])){
        echo'<p> Successful entry.</p>';
        $ps = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, trim($_POST['product_supplier']));
        $ps=$_POST['product_supplier'];
        echo "You chose:".$ps."<br>";}
        else{
            echo '<p>You forgot to enter the product category.</p>';}   

    if(!empty($_POST['product_description'])){
        echo'<p>Successful entry.</p>';
        $pd=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['product_description']));
        $pd=$_POST['product_description'];
        echo"You chose:".$pd."<br>";}
        else{
            echo'<p>You forgot to enter the product_description.</p>';}

//query: Insert into database

$query = "INSERT INTO `products_catalog` (product_name, product_category, product_supplier, product_description) VALUES ('$pn', '$pc', '$ps','$pd')";

$r=@mysqli_query ($dbc,$query);
if($r){
    echo"<h2> You entered the product name:".$pn."</h2>";   
    echo"<h2>You entered the product category:".$pc."</h2>";
    echo"<h2>You entered the product supplier:".$ps."</h2>";
    echo"<h2>You entered the product description:".$pd."</h2>";}
    else{
        echo'<h1>System Error</h1>
        <p>The product name, category, supplier and description could not be entered. We apologize for any inconvenience. Please try again. If error continues, please contact tech support.</p>';

//Debugging message:
echo '<p>'.mysqli_error($dbc).'<br/><br/> Query:'.$query.'</p>';}

//End of if($r) IF.

mysqli_close($dbc); }

?>
```

Comment: Putting single quotes around your variables makes them the literal string "$pn", not your variable.

Comment: Please don't suppress errors like you do in `$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc,$query);` - it makes it much harder debugging

Comment: since you're using mysqli swap to prepared statements too

Comment: @echolocation, are you referring to '$pn' in the VALUES section? That usage is **CORRECT**. It's contained within a "-delimited string, so it will be substituted.

Comment: actually you're also double declaring $ps and $pd you're escaping it  first and then re-defining it as the direct post input i'm guessing one of the inputs has a " or a ' in it on an unescaped string. Dlete the lines that look like this `$pd=$_POST['product_description'];` for all your vars and it'll work

Comment: @PhilPerry Well shoot, I didn't even see that. You are certainly correct!

Comment: I agree with @DHS -- don't suppress error messages with @ unless 1) they're very common, and 2) you know for sure that all are harmless. It would help if you could give us the full error message that says where in the INSERT the syntax error is. The only thing I can think of right now is that one of your $pX variables is empty, or maybe has a ' in it.

Comment: When you already have values using real escape string, why are again re-assigning values from request params? When have `$pd = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbc, trim( $_POST[ 'product_description' ] ) );` then why again this: `$pd = $_POST[ 'product_description' ];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
<?php

if  (isset($_POST['submitted'])){
    include('../mysqli_connect.php');


if (isset($_POST['$pn, $pc,$ps,$pd'])); 

        if(!empty($_POST['product_name'])){
        echo'<p> Successful entry.</p>';
        $pn = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, trim($_POST['product_name']));
        //$pn=$_POST['product_name'];  // THIS LINE NOT REQUIRED
        echo "You chose:".$pn."<br>";}
        else{
            echo '<p>You forgot to enter the product name.</p>';}


        if(!empty($_POST['product_category'])){
        echo'<p> Successful entry.</p>';
        $pc = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, trim($_POST['product_category']));
        //$pc=$_POST['product_category'];  // THIS LINE NOT REQUIRED
        echo "You chose:".$pc."<br>";}
        else{
            echo '<p>You forgot to enter the product category.</p>';}


        if(!empty($_POST['product_supplier'])){
        echo'<p> Successful entry.</p>';
        $ps = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, trim($_POST['product_supplier']));
        //$ps=$_POST['product_supplier'];  // THIS LINE NOT REQUIRED
        echo "You chose:".$ps."<br>";}
        else{
            echo '<p>You forgot to enter the product category.</p>';}   

    if(!empty($_POST['product_description'])){
        echo'<p>Successful entry.</p>';
        $pd=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['product_description']));
        //$pd=$_POST['product_description'];  // THIS LINE NOT REQUIRED
        echo"You chose:".$pd."<br>";}
        else{
            echo'<p>You forgot to enter the product_description.</p>';}

//query: Insert into database

$query = "INSERT INTO `products_catalog` (product_name, product_category, product_supplier, product_description) VALUES ('$pn', '$pc', '$ps','$pd')";

$r=@mysqli_query ($dbc,$query);
if($r){
    echo"<h2> You entered the product name:".$pn."</h2>";   
    echo"<h2>You entered the product category:".$pc."</h2>";
    echo"<h2>You entered the product supplier:".$ps."</h2>";
    echo"<h2>You entered the product description:".$pd."</h2>";}
    else{
        echo'<h1>System Error</h1>
        <p>The product name, category, supplier and description could not be entered. We apologize for any inconvenience. Please try again. If error continues, please contact tech support.</p>';

//Debugging message:
echo '<p>'.mysqli_error($dbc).'<br/><br/> Query:'.$query.'</p>';}

//End of if($r) IF.

mysqli_close($dbc); }

?>
```

Comment: Dave, that solved the error and the writing to the database. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO products_catalog (product_name, product_category, product_supplier, product_description) VALUES ('".$pn."', '".$pc."', '".$ps."','".$pd."')";
```

It'll probably fix the error.

:)

Comment: no it won't if his input var has a ' or a " in it because he's not escaping his input string look closely `$ps = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, trim($_POST['product_supplier']));
        $ps=$_POST['product_supplier'];`

Comment: I don't exactly how this function works,but if he put the variables he wants to escape it'll work, am I right? Something like that:        $pn = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['product_description']);

Comment: Why don't just use $query = `"INSERT INTO products_catalog (product_name, product_category, product_supplier, product_description) VALUES ('$pn', '$pc', '$ps','$pd')";`

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if this is going to work, it looks like it'll store exactly the name of the values: $pn, $pc, $ps and $pd. For example: INSERT INTO hi VALUES('HELLO') is equals INSERT INTO hi VALUES('$ps') -- In the first example we store the value 'HELLO' and in the second example the value '$ps'

Comment: no it won't as the overall sql string is in " which means that php will process the string and replace $ps with the value of the var $ps the problem he has is that he is setting $ps (and the others) with an escaped string and then overwriting those variables with the plain $_POST var again so if the post var includes say "don't" then it'll break his sql string as it'll become "... VALUES ('don't', '', '', '')" which is an invalid sql statement as it'll have 3 single quotes in it

Comment: He could do that so: $pn = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['product_description']); and take it off the $_POST part

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. You guys are awesome. Dave's solution solved the problem, it is now writing to the database.

Comment: @AlanD. he was already doing that but the problem was he was overwriting his vars with the raw post data after so his real escape string was doing nothing and so it was breaking his sql.